# How to track which application displays what window in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

I have a weird window appearing sometimes when I leave my mouse cursor on the taskbar. As soon as I move the mouse, the window disappears.

Is there something I can leave running for hours and when I see this window pop-up, I look at the software and it tells me what application spawned the window? I am using Windows 10. I already tried Process Monitor and Sysmon and I don't see anything to filter by displayed windows.

[image: Weird cyan window with something that looks like a progress bar]

Comment: Is that a mock-up or a real screenshot?

Comment: This is a real screenshot. If I right-click the mouse without moving it, part of the window goes behind the taskbar.

Comment: in process explorer, there is a cross-hairs icon you can drag over a window to have procexp automatically select the process that created it. Click and hold it, then drag over the window and let go.

Comment: @FrankThomas the problem is I can't do that because the window disappears as soon as I move the mouse.

Comment: Where on the taskbar is it? You could run this continuously in a loop https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html (eg `:loop`, `c:\somefolder\winlist.exe`, and `goto loop`). However windows like this are usually shown/hidden rather than created/destroyed. So look for windows that a child windows/owned windows by the taskbar window.

Comment: @Mark I actually used WinLister from NirSoft and waited for the window to appear and it showed up in the app. It was actually JDownloader, and the window uses white text that's only readable when zooming in!

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out this is the JDownloader 'Windows Taskbar Progress'. I used WinLister to find out what it was and disabled it in JDownloader in 'Advanced Settings' by setting 'Windows Taskbar Progress Display' to 'Nothing'.